# How to take snapshot in vlc using command line in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, vlc

I am using easycap DC60+ in ubuntu and watch easycap video on vlc using following command:

```
vlc -vvv v4l2:///dev/video1:input=1:norm=PAL-I:width=720:height=576 --input-slave=alsa://plughw:1,0 --v4l2-standard=PAL_I
```

and i want to take snapshot of vlc using command line.

I use this command on another terminal but show error and my first instance of vlc not work properly

```
vlc -I dummy v4l2:///dev/video0 --video-filter scene --no-audio --scene-path /home/stoppal/test --scene-prefix image_prefix --scene-format png vlc://quit --run-time=1
```

this error is occure

```
[0x19d6aa8] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
libv4l2: error set_fmt gave us a different result then try_fmt!
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need "dummy" it's for example purposes.
Here is the command you can use :

```
vlc -I v4l2:///dev/video{id} --video-filter scene --no-audio --scene-path /home/stoppal/test --scene-prefix image_prefix --scene-format {format} vlc://quit --run-time=1
```